# Defining a container view as member

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a container view and I want to have it as a member in another view so that I can use its name for actions. I want to add this line:

```
@IBOutlet var buyContainer: UIView!
```

but it doesn't seem to work. I try to right-click and drag the container view to the main view's code, but it just switches to the container view's code.

Both views have classes as seen in the picture below.

In the picture below is my container view.

[image]

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Are you trying to drag the view of the container view controller or the view of the container view added to the main view controller?

Comment: I was dragging the view of the container view...

Comment: Help, anyone ? I'm still stuck on this